# Jenkins multibranch with Jenkinsfile in different repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

If use a multibranch pipeline in Jenkins, I want to have a build for every specific branch that is made inside my code repo. This works like a charm. But I don't want to provide a Jenkinsfile inside my code repo. Instead I want to define a different CI repo which is providing my CI pipeline scripts.

The problem is that the usual config is not containing the scm option like in the normal config.

Normal pipeline config:

[image]

Multibranch pipeline config:

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to separate the Jenkinsfile from my source code using a multibranch pipeline?

Comment: Why do you want to seperate your Jenkinsfile from your repository? The idea behind a multibranch pipeline is that each branch has a Jenkinsfile that is executed when a commit is made on the branch so basically you are fighting against the idea of the multibranch pipeline.

Comment: Like @justaprogrammer said: its the idea to give the developers the insights and the power of how their software is built. Can you explain the rason why you dont want that?

Comment: We use a CI pipline definition for more that just one project. If I would lay the Jenkinsfile on the source repo, I would copy it. The second thing is that I want to use a definition for short living branches like feature branches other than long living branches like develop or master. So the way to go would be to have the Jenkinsfile in a different repo. Why is that going against the idea of a multibranch pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stunmles over the same problem,
there is a Jenkins plug-in which brings remote Jenkinsfiles for mutlibranch pipleines: https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file/